# Reading responses python

Tags: python

For what I am making i am reading response, and when the response is blank / nothing it send me a message, but I don't know how to read that / what to do

```
if "\"status\": \"ok\"" in response:
        self.attempts += 1
    elif "<i have no idea>" in response:
```

Any help is great, thanks.

Comment: Is there only one string that means success or multiple? If there is a single type then a simple if/else would be fine. If the response is nothing then you can do a ``if (response == "") ``

Comment: Can you specify your question?

Answer (score 0):

A try except would work here. Also, you might keep another attribute in the class and update it separately

Answer (score 0):

As we could not see entire requests call, assuming you're trying to check the response status you could do the below,

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('foo')
else:
   print(response)
```

or

```
if response.text = '':
    print('blank')
else:
   print(response.text)
```